# CloudFormation template: how to use Sub and GetAtt at the same time in short form?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, yaml

I'm using yaml. So, we can use either:

```
!GetAtt [ WebServer, AvailabilityZone ]
!GetAtt WebServer.AvailabilityZone
```

Also, we can use:

```
!Sub 'sometext-${AWS::StackName}'
```

how can I use GetAtt output instead of `${AWS::StackName}`, preferably using the second form of `GetAtt`? I do know how to use `Join` but I'd like to stay with `Sub`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply remove !GetAtt and reference the desired variable.  In the following code EIP.AllocationId normally returned via !GetAtt.

```
!Sub |
#!/bin/bash
export INSTANCEID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCEID --allow-reassociation --allocation-id ${EIP.AllocationId} --region ${AWS::Region}
```